# Does mapreduce program consumes all the files (input dataset) in a folder by default?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Hello good folks at Stackoverflow,

I ran a mapreduce code that finds the unique words in a file. The input dataset (file) was in a folder in HDFS. So I gave the name of the folder as input when I ran the mapreduce program.

I didn't realize that there were another 2 more files in the same folder. Mapreduce program went ahead and read thru all the 3 files and gave the output. The output is fine.

Is this the default behaviour of mapreduce? Meaning if you point to a folder and not just a file (as input dataset), the mapreduce consumes all the files in that folder? The reason I am  surprised is that in the mapper, there is no code to read multiple files. I understand that the first argument args[0] in the driver program is the folder name I gave.

**This is the driver code:**

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

public class DataSort {

     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

/*
 * Validate that two arguments were passed from the command line.
 */
if (args.length != 2) {
  System.out.printf("Usage: StubDriver <input dir> <output dir>\n");
  System.exit(-1);
}

Job job=Job.getInstance();

/*
 * Specify the jar file that contains your driver, mapper, and reducer.
 * Hadoop will transfer this jar file to nodes in your cluster running 
 * mapper and reducer tasks.
 */
job.setJarByClass(DataSort.class);

/*
 * Specify an easily-decipherable name for the job.
 * This job name will appear in reports and logs.
 */
job.setJobName("Data Sort");

/*
 * TODO implement
 */
FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(args[0]));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

job.setMapperClass(ValueIdentityMapper.class);
job.setReducerClass(IdentityReducer.class);

job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

/*
 * Start the MapReduce job and wait for it to finish.
 * If it finishes successfully, return 0. If not, return 1.
 */
boolean success = job.waitForCompletion(true);
System.exit(success ? 0 : 1);
  }
}
```

**Mapper Code:**

```
import java.io.IOException;  
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;

public class ValueIdentityMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

 @Override
  public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
  throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    String line=value.toString();
    for (String word:line.split("\\W+"))
    {
        if (word.length()>0)
        {
            context.write(new Text(word),new IntWritable(1));
        }
    }

 }
```

}

**Reducer Code:**

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;

public class IdentityReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, Text>    {

 @Override
 public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)
  throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    String word="";
    context.write(key, new Text(word));
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this the default behaviour of mapreduce?

Not of mapreduce, just of the InputFormat you used.

[`FileInputFormat`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/FileInputFormat.html) API Reference

> `setInputPaths(JobConf conf, Path... inputPaths)`
>
> Set the array of `Path`s as the list of inputs for the map-reduce job.

[`Path`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/Path.html) API Reference

> Names a file **or directory** in a `FileSystem`.

So, when you say

> there is no code to read multiple files

Yes, there actually is, use just didn't need to write it.

`Mapper<LongWritable, Text,` properly handles all file-offsets for all files in the specified `InputFormat`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Since being new to mapreduce, I am trying all sorts of stuff. Say If I want to print out in the log file, the input arguments to the main () method how can I do that. I tried to put System.out.println statements in the driver class. At the end of the run, I went to the URL to track that job and I don't see any of my println statements. Println statements in mapper and reducer work fine. But not in the driver. Any reason why?